# Is there any definitive reason not to check .aspx designer files into TFS source control

Tags: asp.net, version-control, tfs

There've been a lot of general StackOverflow questions about checking auto-generated files into source control, and specifically the pros and cons of checking in .aspx designer files.  My question is whether there any *definitive* **technical** reason anyone knows of that designer files should *not* be committed to source control, that would create definite issues that outweigh the advantages of committing?  My current thinking is that designer files should be in source control for the following reasons:

- Designer files aren't always reliably re-generated.  It's common for a control definition to go missing, and this can waste time when identifying the cause of a failed build, and they can be tricky to re-generate, so checking the files in facilitates manual recovery of lost control definitions and highlights where a breaking change to the designer file has occurred
- TFS when correctly configured, should always check out or mark for an 'add' a designer file that's been auto-modified or generated, meaning that when a solution is checked in, any changes to the generated file will be included by default
- Developers should always be reviewing the files that are being committed, so in theory should be safely committing any designer files that have changed
- In the case of needing to merge changes to these designer files that have been made by other developers, this is also a routine operation in a collaborative environment that it should be possible to do safely as part of any well-disciplined source control process
- So, to my mind, there's a good argument for always committing designer files - any compelling reason that this in general should *not* be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.designer.cs files are not "auto-generated". They are generated by the designer when the .aspx file is created, and are updated as markup changes. They need to be checked into source control.